# What on Earth is a "mute module"?

Tags: consumer-electronics, engineering-history

Studying the extremely intimidating manual for my newly found and rescued 1989 JVC television set, which makes me feel very stupid and as if I'm looking at some sort of alien technology, I found this page for a "MUTE MODULE":

[image]

Surely this cannot be a physical card inside the TV which is dedicated for the "mute" feature? Why does this have to be such a complicated thing? Why doesn't it simply set the audio connection on/off? Or does this have nothing to do with the "mute" feature?

Comment: Not sure if this is the actually answer but apparently make things mute with popping or other artificacts is not a trivial task.

Comment: @DKNguyen "Mute with popping"?

Comment: Yeah. When you mute you are interrupting an audio signal and your ears are going to pick that up. For example, if it were mechanical contacts you could hear the arcing due to the contacts scraping and chatter from the contacts bouncing. It's not much different if a solid-state switch were used.

Comment: that probably mutes the sound when no video signal is detected ... it prevents the white noise from speakers when tuned off station

Comment: @jsotola That would make sense why it taps into the feed to detect the sync pulse.